# Change Names of Multiple Files Linux

Tags: linux, file-rename

I have a number of files with names a1.txt, b1.txt, c1,txt...on ubuntu machine.

Is there any quick way to change all file names to a2.txt, b2.txt, c2.txt...?

In particular, I'd like to replace part of the name string. For instance, every file name contains a string called "apple" and I want to replace "apple" with "pear" in all file names.

Any command or script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

without any extra software you can:

```
for FILE in *1.txt; do mv "$FILE" $(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/1/2/'); done
```

Comment: To replace multiple occurence replace sed 's/1/2/' by sed 's/1/2/g'

Answer (score 5):

```
for f in {a..c}1.txt; do echo "$f" "${f/1/2}"; done
```

replace 'echo' with 'mv' if the output looks correct.

> and I want to replace "apple" with "linux"

```
for f in *apple*; do mv "$f" "${f/apple/linux}"; done
```

The curly brackets in line 1 should work with bash at least.

Comment: @River: What didn't work for you? In which shell? {a..c}  works in bash.

Comment: Well, first, I figured replacing linux with pear would be the more obvious fix as "apple"->"pear" is the example in the OP and pear was clearly the intent while linux was a copy/paste remnant. Second, your second command needs `done` affixed to the end otherwise it prompts for it. Third, while the curly braces do work, I find the `*` wildcard operator to be more widely applicable (which is the point on SO) and also more intuitive. (This third point is more of an opinion and you do use `*` in your second example, so I would be ok if you left your first command as is.)

Comment: Your idea to `echo` the files first to make sure of correct output before the actual action (Linux can be quite unforgiving of small typos/mistakes) makes this answer a bit better than the accepted I feel, but I don't feel that I can support it unless it 1: does the same thing it claims to do (the linux/pear mix-up in your original answer) and 2: works immediately when copy/pasted as a command (which it requires the `done` to do)

Comment: @River: {a..c}1.txt is very much more narrow solution than *1.txt . If the reader understands it, it is easily adopted to ranges to m, n or z while *1.txt is a very rough match. I'm sorry for overseeing the 'done'. That was my fault and I would have recognized it, hadn't it not been lost in arbitrary changes from 'right' to 'correct'. The humorous change from apple to linux instead from apple to pear will most reader understand immediately, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The following command will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of `1` in their name by `2`:

```
rename 1 2 *1.txt
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me on CentOS 5.

Comment: Ah! There is a `rename` as `/usr/bin/prename: a /usr/bin/perl -w script text executable` on linux, which works differently. I would revoke my downvote, but it is locked, as long as the posting isn't edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *1.txt | perl -ne 'chomp; $x = $_; $x =~ s/1/2/; rename $_, $x;'
```

Comment: Don't parse the output of ls in scripts. It is vulnerable to all sorts of special characters in filenames, to begin with: Blanks, tabs, * and ?.

Comment: @user - that is generally good advice, and that is why I wouldn't embed the above code in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that worked for me (following the examples above) for files in different subdirectories

```
for FILE in $(find . -name *1.txt); do mv "$FILE" "${FILE/1/2}"; done;
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
for i in *1.txt; do
    name=$(echo $i | cut -b1)
    mv $i ${name}2.txt
done
```

Modify to suit your needs.